# Rotate CALayers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, calayer, quartz-graphics

I've done following tutorial to create a rotating Wheel Control with UIKit. 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit

In the section "Laying out the Wheel" of the tutorial, the wheel is drawn clockwise starting at the left site of the circle (See the screenshot with the red labels). So it begins with 0 from the left site.

However. I would like to start at the right site of the circle with the value 0 - where now is 4 on the screenshot. Unfortunately I have no idea how I could achieve this. Of course the rotation of the numbers or pictures should be exactly the opposite like its now. So where now 4 is rotated 180 degrees it should be normal.

Can anybody help me here ? Would be great.

Regards

Current drawWheel function:

```
// 3 - Create the sectors
for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfSections; i++) {
    // 4 - Create image view
    UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment.png"]];
    im.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
    im.layer.position = CGPointMake(_container.bounds.size.width/2.0-_container.frame.origin.x,
                                    _container.bounds.size.height/2.0-_container.frame.origin.y);
    im.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((angleSize * i) + M_PI);
    im.alpha = minAlphavalue;
    im.tag = i;
    if (i == 0) {
        im.alpha = maxAlphavalue;
    }
    // 5 - Set sector image
    UIImageView *sectorImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 100, 40, 40)];
    sectorImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%i.png", i]];
    [im addSubview:sectorImage];
    // 6 - Add image view to container
    [_container addSubview:im];
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the wheel as it's now]

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but can't you just add `M_PI`?

```
- (void) drawWheel {
    container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    CGFloat angleSize = 2*M_PI/numberOfSections;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        UILabel *im = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
        im.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        im.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        im.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
        im.layer.position = CGPointMake(container.bounds.size.width/2.0, 
                                        container.bounds.size.height/2.0); 
        // ===== Add M_PI Here! =====
        im.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((angleSize * i) + M_PI);
        // ==========================
        im.tag = i;
        [container addSubview:im];
    }
    container.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self addSubview:container];
}
```

Comment: Hello trojanfoe! Thanks for your answer, now it's starting just as I want. Only the images are not rotated correctly, hmm isn't this done with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is adding `M_PI` to the call to `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()`.  Can you please confirm that you have the exact code I have posted (less the comments with `====` in them)?

Comment: My code is a bit different, because I use images instead of labels.

My drawWheel function now looks like in the section "Adding Graphics" of the tutorial. (At the bottom of the page)